# Does flushing a a top level stream end up flushing all nested streams that the top level stream implicitly wraps?

Tags: c#, .net-core, filestream

```
using var fs = new FileStream(...);
using var textWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
textWriter.Write("foo");
textWriter.Flush();
```

Would textWriter.Flush only flush to the file stream which is buffering data which would require me to flush the file stream aswell? Would I have to build an abstraction for flushing like so:

```
void Flush()
{
    textWriter.Flush();
    /*any other decorators in between*/
    fs.Flush();
}
```

Or does flushing that top level stream (the textWriter flush all underlying streams as well?)

Comment: There aren't multiple / nested streams in your code. Just one stream.

Comment: Oh yes my bad thought adapters/decorators were all considered streams.